# Are there any miracles in the holy Quran?

Tags: quran, miracles

Are there any miracles in Quran such as fact it contains, that people at the time had no knowledge about but later they know it was the truth or it is associated with an event that can only be miracle or it is associated with something miraculous? I am not asking about the miracles mentioned in the Quran.

Comment: please specify you mean miracles of prophets mentioned in stories in Quran. or miracles today acceptable by non-Muslim scientists as a miracle bracking Natural laws.

Comment: I think it would be good to clarify the question a little bit. Right now it is not clear if you are talking about 1) miracles performed by our prophet and mentioned in Quran, 2) Quran itself as a miracle, 3) miracles by other prophets and mentioned in Quran.

Comment: I heard miracles like if you are in hot dessert and there is no where you can hide, quran will provide shadow for you. Or may be some thing that was told to us in Quran, the chances of it happening was close to 0 but it happened after 1300 years or so. But the question is aimed at first type of miracles but would like to know the second type as well.

Comment: This is whole site is just for you.... 
Miracles of Qur'an - Proven and talks science that most of us don't know... http://www.speed-light.info/miracles_of_quran/

Comment: 4 answers where given before muslim1 clarified question in comment and they where not changed since that and they are now not appropiate. then there were not new answers for long time. then appeared answer of Zohal. then muslim1 edited his question at Nov 20 '15 at 17:22 and its meaning is again changed. then appeared answer of ysn_akst.

Comment: "or it is associated with an event that can only be miracle or it is associated with something miraculous? I am not asking about the miracles mentioned in the Quran" - i understand here as contradiction. please edit.

Answer (score 6):

They're indeed 14 miracles done by prophets which have been mentioned explicitly. You might look at their meaning and interpretations to find out the story behind them:

> - Al-Qamar: The Hour has come near, and the moon has split in two
> - Taha: And We had inspired to Moses, "Travel by night with My servants and strike for them a dry path through the sea; you will not fear being overtaken [by Pharaoh] nor be afraid [of drowning]."(77)
> - Taha: And draw in your hand to your side; it will come out white without disease - another sign,(22)
> - Al-baqarah: And [mention] when Abraham said, "My Lord, show me how You give life to the dead." [ Allah ] said, "Have you not believed?" He said, "Yes, but [I ask] only that my heart may be satisfied." [ Allah ] said, "Take four birds and commit them to yourself. Then [after slaughtering them] put on each hill a portion of them; then call them - they will come [flying] to you in haste. And know that Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise."(260)
> - Al-Isra': Exalted is He who took His Servant by night from al-Masjid al-Haram to al-Masjid al- Aqsa, whose surroundings We have blessed, to show him of Our signs. Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Seeing.(1)
> - Saba: And to Solomon [We subjected] the wind - its morning [journey was that of] a month - and its afternoon [journey was that of] a month, and We made flow for him a spring of [liquid] copper. And among the jinn were those who worked for him by the permission of his Lord. And whoever deviated among them from Our command - We will make him taste of the punishment of the Blaze.(12)
> - Al-anbia': They said, "Burn him and support your gods - if you are to act."(68) Allah said, "O fire, be coolness and safety upon Abraham."(69) And they intended for him harm, but We made them the greatest losers.(70)
> - Al-ankabut: But We saved him and the companions of the ship, and We made it a sign for the worlds.(15)
> - Ali imran: And [make him] a messenger to the Children of Israel, [who will say], 'Indeed I have come to you with a sign from your Lord in that I design for you from clay [that which is] like the form of a bird, then I breathe into it and it becomes a bird by permission of Allah . And I cure the blind and the leper, and I give life to the dead - by permission of Allah . And I inform you of what you eat and what you store in your houses. Indeed in that is a sign for you, if you are believers.(49)

Which includes three miracles.

> - Al-araf: So Moses threw his staff, and suddenly it was a serpent, manifest.(107)
> - Ash-shoara: Then We inspired to Moses, "Strike with your staff the sea," and it parted, and each portion was like a great towering mountain.
>   (63)
> - An-naml: And put your hand into the opening of your garment [at the breast]; it will come out white without disease. [These are] among the nine signs [you will take] to Pharaoh and his people. Indeed, they have been a people defiantly disobedient."(12)

Answer (score 3):

There are many miracles told in the Qur'an, like the raising of Jesus:

> بَل رَّفَعَهُ ٱللَّهُ إِلَيۡهِ‌ۚ وَكَانَ ٱللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمً۬ا
> (١٥٨)
>
> Nay, Allah raised him up unto Himself; and Allah is Exalted in Power, Wise. (158)

Surat 4 Ayah 158

And there is the Isra'a:

> سُبۡحَـٰنَ ٱلَّذِىٓ أَسۡرَىٰ بِعَبۡدِهِۦ لَيۡلاً۬ مِّنَ ٱلۡمَسۡجِدِ ٱلۡحَرَامِ إِلَى ٱلۡمَسۡجِدِ ٱلۡأَقۡصَا ٱلَّذِى بَـٰرَكۡنَا حَوۡلَهُ ۥ لِنُرِيَهُ ۥ مِنۡ ءَايَـٰتِنَآ‌ۚ إِنَّهُ ۥ هُوَ ٱلسَّمِيعُ ٱلۡبَصِيرُ (١)
>
> mi>Glory to (Allah) Who did take His Servant for Journey by night
> from the Sacred Mosque to the Farthest Mosque whose precincts We did
> bless― in order that Weght show him some of Our Signs: for He is the
> one Who heareth and seeth (all things). (1)

But The biggest of all miracles is the Qur'an itself.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this question I asked before:
[Did the stories in Quran happen as is, or are they symbolizing different and more common events?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/562/4)

There is a strong possibility that stories and terms in Quran are symbolizing more realistic events. Quran is not a fantasy book, it is a realistic book that brings solutions to humanity in all eras and ages. It must be pointing out the actual and realistic facts by telling us that kind of stories.

Quran is only 600+ pages. Text in its pages are not condensed. In an ordinary page of it, there is approximately 20% of text compared to any other text book. When you condense it to a standard text book format, it becomes only 100-150 pages. And, I have to add that, most of the Quran is repeating the same stories, warnings and phrases. For example, story of Musa (Moses) is told 50+ times. If you remove the duplicating parts, it becomes only about 50 pages.

Now there is a problem of `condensed information`.
Supposed that you are working in an information department. They wanted you to write a book, consisting of only 50 pages, or 150 pages with repeating parts, which will be a solution to the entire problems of the world, will bring a perfect system for daily life, and will be perfectly consistent inside.
And, also suppose that, you had never heard of Quran before. What would you write in your book?

Quran is a solution of this problem of `condensed information`. No human can solve this problem and write a similar book solving all the problems of human. A special book like that must have a special way of explaining the issues (i.e.; with those supernatural stories). Unfortunately, most people think this kind of things with a skeptic mind, it is not possible to discuss these kind of things openly.

Answer (score 2):

Surah Lahab is also considered as miracle of Quran

If you notice, Allah dooms Abu Lahab to Hellfire in this surah. Now, the mufassireen (interpreters) point out an interesting point–at any time, Abu Lahab could have accepted Islam–even as a fake-out. And he could have said “Hey guys, I’m Muslim now, how come the Qur’an is claiming I’m in Hellfire?” And that would’ve caused great fitnah.

But he never did.

And Allah knew that he wouldn’t.

And so, we see even in this small, oft-repeated surah, one of the miracles of the Qur’an. More about Surah Lahab can be read [here](http://www.ilmfruits.com/tafseer-of-surah-lahab)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is asking does the Qur'an mention any miracles:

The Qur'an makes mention of many miracles which took place to help the Prophets and the believers.

If your question is asking is the Qur'an a miracle:

The Qur'an is the words of Allah and sent down the the Prophet Muhammad (saw) the Angel Jibrael. Therefore it is a miracle.

If your question is asking can the Qur'an be used as a miracle:
The Qur'an can be used as a protection. The verses can be read to keep you safe. The Qur'an is a medicine. The words can cure an ill person. Reciting the Qur'an has many benefits. I have even read once in an article that it has been scientifically proven that reciting the Qur'an or even just listening to a recitation improves our memory and keeps our brains health. It also boost up our immunize system. Recting Ayat Al Kursi acts as a barrier against all evil and nothing can harm us. Even if a thief was to rob you they would lose their way be unsuccessful. These are all miracles and the blessing of Allah.

Comment: I appreciate your response which has stated from different aspects and angels. Well done. و من الله توفیق

Answer (score 0):

There are miracles of prophets as Gigili mentioned. But also, The Qur'an is a miracle

> But they say, "Why are not signs sent down to him from his Lord?" Say, "The signs are only with Allah, and I am only a clear warner. And is it not sufficient for them that We revealed to you the Book which is recited to them? Indeed in that is a mercy and reminder for a people who believe." [29:50-51}

You can check this book out http://www.quranmiracles.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/The-Quran-Unchallengeable-Miracle.pdf