# What miracles are mentioned in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, miracles

What I mean by a miracle are things like the Staff of Moses which transformed into a serpent or opened up the river of Nile, or the clothes of Joseph which healed Jacob's blind eyes.

Are there any more mentions of miracles in the Qur'an?

Comment: [This](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/779/are-there-any-miracles-in-the-holy-quran?rq=1) question isn't about what I'm asking. The OP says: "I am not asking about the miracles mentioned in the Quran."

Comment: Could you add references to the stories you mentioned? I don't remember a dragon.

Comment: @G.Bach [A'raf 107](https://quran.com/7/107): Then (Moses) threw his rod, and behold! it was a [serpent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent_(symbolism)), plain (for all to see)! Though I'm not sure what word exactly needs to be used. Not sure what a serpent is :D. Do you suggest I replace dragon with serpent?

Comment: "Serpent" is a somewhat archaic word for large snakes. I don't know what the mufassirun said whether it was a dragon, and I don't know Arabic, but in the Bible it's snakes, and in most Quran translations I've seen too. Still, would be worthwhile adding the references to your question.

Comment: @G.Bach I'll just edit it from dragon to serpent and keep as translation.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have grouped magic (sihr) and miracles. There is a fundamental difference them and considering them the same is Kufr, e.g. [27:13](https://quran.com/27/13)

Comment: @Uma I meant miracles, but yeah if we are being literal you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite difficult to list Allah's miracles, even if restricted to those mentioned in the Qur'an.  Isn't every word in the Qur'an a miracle?

Here's a (likely incomplete) list where Allah specifically intervened and scientific laws were radically overruled:

1. The creation of the Heavens and the Earth ([Qur'an 2:29](https://quran.com/2/29)).
2. The creation of man ([Qur'an 3:59](https://quran.com/3/59)).
3. Prophet Muhammad's night journey ([Qur'an 17:1](https://quran.com/17/1)).
4. The Moon splitting in two ([Qur'an 54:1](https://quran.com/54/1)).
5. The revelation of the Qur'an itself ([Qur'an 17:88](https://quran.com/17/88)).
6. Virgin Mary giving birth to Prophet Isa ([Qur'an 19:20](https://quran.com/19/20)).
7. Prophet Isa breathing life into a clay bird ([Qur'an 3:49](https://quran.com/3/49)).
8. Prophet Isa curing the blind and the leper ([Qur'an 3:49](https://quran.com/3/49)).
9. Prophet Isa giving life to the dead ([Qur'an 3:49](https://quran.com/3/49)).
10. Prophet Isa speaking from the cradle ([Qur'an 19:29](https://quran.com/19/29)).
11. The raising of Prophet Isa ([Qur'an 4:158](https://quran.com/4/158)).
12. Prophet Musa's staff consuming magicians' conjurations ([Qur'an 26:45](https://quran.com/26/45)).
13. Prophet Musa parting the seas ([Qur'an 26:63](https://quran.com/26/63)).
14. Prophet Musa bringing forth twelve springs from a stone ([Qur'an 2:60](https://quran.com/2/60)).
15. Prophet Nuh and the flood ([Qur'an 11:44](https://quran.com/11/44)).
16. Prophet Nuh lived for 950+ years ([Qur'an 29:14](https://quran.com/29/14)).
17. Prophet Jonah swallowed by the big fish ([Qur'an 37:142](https://quran.com/37/142)).
18. Destruction of the people of 'Ad ([Qur'an 46:25](https://quran.com/46/25)).
19. Destruction of the people of Lut ([Qur'an 11:82](https://quran.com/11/82)).
20. Destruction of the people who disbelieved Prophet Shu'ayb ([Qur'an 11:94](http://quran.com/11:94)).
21. Destruction of the people who disbelieved Prophet Saleh ([Qur'an 27:51](https://quran.com/27/51)).
22. Prophet Yusef's ability to interpret dreams ([Qur'an 12:43](https://quran.com/12/43)).
23. Prophet Abraham shown Heavens and Earth ([Qur'an 6:75](https://quran.com/6/75)).
24. Prophet Abraham Bringing dead birds back to life ([Qur'an 2:260](https://quran.com/2/260)).
25. Prophet Abraham thrown into fire, but which was made cool ([Qur'an 21:69](https://quran.com/21/69)).
26. Prophet Abraham sacrificing his son ([Qur'an 37:103-107](https://quran.com/37/103-107)).
27. Prophet Sulaiman and the spring of liquid copper ([Qur'an 34:12](https://quran.com/34/12)).
28. Prophet Sulaiman spoke to birds (Qur'an [27:22](https://quran.com/27/22) and [38:19](https://quran.com/38/19)).
29. Prophet Yaqub's clothes curing his father's (Prophet Jacob) blindness ([Qur'an 12:93](https://quran.com/12/93)).
30. Prophet Uzair died for 100 years and was revived ([Qur'an 2:259](https://quran.com/2/259)).
31. The dwellers of the cave slept for years ([Qur'an 18:11](https://quran.com/18/11)).

Every [Prophet named in the Qur'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_and_names_mentioned_in_the_Quran#Prophets) has some miraculous element to their story (or else they wouldn't be a Prophet).  There's a Wikipedia list of [Miracles of Muhammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracles_of_Muhammad) (many are hadith-based).  There are also things I'm unsure if I should list, like angels and jinn, and Allah's [she-camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Camel_of_God).

See also: [Are there any miracles in the holy Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/779/are-there-any-miracles-in-the-holy-quran)

Comment: This is an awesome list. Thanks Do you mind adding this to the list: https://quran.com/2/259?translations=20 (prophet uzair being dead for 100 years)

Comment: Prophet Solomon speaking to animals: https://quran.com/27/22?translations=20

Comment: Not sure if we should include prophet Noah's age or not :D

Comment: Calf having sounds made by Samiri https://quran.com/7/148?translations=20 & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_calf) && God reviving the 70 men who joined Prophet Musa to see Allah. https://quran.com/2/56?translations=20

Comment: Another miracle, Pharaoh preserved in dead body: https://quran.com/10/92

Answer (score 0):

Very nice list. How about - Prophet Moses speaking to Allah, Mountain crumbling into pieces due to Allahs light, birth of hazrath Hawwa from Hazrath Adam